# Convert 16 bit signed to signed int in C

Tags: c

I try to convert a 16 bit signed number to `int` in C. The number is big endian and stored in two arrays which contain 8 bit each. I am successful with this code with positive numbers, but not with negative:

```
measurement_raw = (RFin_bytes[6] << 8) | RFin_bytes[7] ;
```

I first thought this should be rather easy and I might find some hints in the web, but failed so far to find working code. Can anyone please help me or guide me to the answer?

Comment: You should add types (probably `int` and `char`?) to your code.

Comment: You can convert a signed 16-bit int to C with `(int)x`, but it looks from your code like you have an array of bytes, two of which somehow encode a 16-bit signed number. Are they unsigned or signed? Are they 8-bits? Is the first the most significant byte and the other the least significant byte?

Comment: @Mike That looks wrong. Did you test it with value like 0x1FFF? Or 0xFFFF?

Comment: @Mike it's likely that the cast isn't doing anything there. Probably the byte and `int16_t` promote to `int` before the arithmetic is done.

Comment: You should cast the first value to 16 Bit an than OR the second one. something like: `((int16_t)RFin_bytes[6])<<8 | RFin_bytes[7]`

Comment: @Mike `(int16_t)RFin_bytes[6])<<8` risks UB shifting in the sign-bit.

Comment: Simon2019, "I am successful with this code with positive numbers, but not with negative:" --> Rather than only describe a failed case, post the inputs used, output seen and output expected.  This will improve the question.